# Best way to store CSV File on MySQL - Blob or text?

Tags: mysql, file, csv, storage

Title says most of it.

I need to store CSV files on my db, mostly will be bellow de 500kb in size (maximum of 2mbs). I'm not sure what was going to be the best way to store it.

in a Blob field as binary or Text field as text;

been searching it for a while but mostly came accross articles on how to import the actual data into table, not the file or it's content on a field.

Comment: Binary might be more compact (by some amount).  Also, have you considered using a NoSQL solution such as Mongo here, which might be better suited to storing documents?

Comment: I actually need the files to be on my mysql db, but I thank you for suggesting it. and thanks for the blob suggestion also.

Comment: I don't think you'll find any single "right" answer to this, but... just curious why you want to store such content within a database, vs storing somewhere else like a network share, cloud storage, etc and then just storing a uri to the data, within your database. There's not much of a case to be made for storing non-metadata "binary" content within a database (if it's not used for searching, it's just adding bulk to your database).

Comment: There are valid reasons to store such files in a database. They obey transaction isolation, and rollback. Also your database backup will include all your CSV files, and supports snapshots so you get a consistent backup. These things are not possible if you store CSV files outside the database.

Comment: mostly for the rollback reasons, I need the file to be on par with the data that refeers it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information you've provided so far, there's no clear answer.

If you use TEXT, your CSV content will have to store valid characters according to the character set of your column. For example, if you store as UTF8 but then the CSV data contains some SMP encodings (like emojis for example), they might be corrupted, or the insert might fail.

Whereas BLOB will store byte-by-byte faithfully, but you won't be able to search the data using UTF8 collations.

Comment: i don't really need to search the data, I believe I'm going with BLOB since it may cause me less trouble